# Using CoreWindow swapchain in xaml project, why is nothing drawn?

Tags: c#, c++, xaml, windows-8, directx

I am currently working on a Win8 project that uses C# and XAML for the frontend of the application and C++ with DirectX for the graphically intensive part.
Because it's mainly centered on real-time graphics and input I decided to use a SwapChain created for the CoreWindow.

While I managed to get the rendering thread running by binding it to the CompositionTarget the screen is still black. The drawing code works fine, it did with ImageSurfaceSource, I switched to a SwapChain recently.

Even though no part of the initialisation returns any errors can any of you shed some light on  why it doesn't draw anything?

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 1):

Exact same issue, I use a swap chain my entire screen goes black.
By backend is c++ **windows runtime component**, and actual execution code resides in C# win 8 project.

The same code starts working placed within a c++ project.

---

## Steps to recreate the error:

( I used interop codes from here: [interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx) ) to present to a SwapChainBackgroundPanel )

1. c++ **windows runtime component**, takes the swapchain, and presents.
2. I add this component to a c++ blank store app, and the render works fine.
3. Add the same component project to a C# blank store app // then create a swapChainPanel .. and pass it. This is where I end up with a blank screen.

## Solution:

I set the `CompositionTarget.Rendering += OnRendering; // the render event`

while navigating. Now I note that I never actually navigate.

So renderer never got called ... Adding the event on constructor solved my case.